# Tensorflow top_k output as a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have output from Tensorflow `top_k` as below:

```
pred_val = tf.argmax(prediction, 1)
pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
pred_top_5 = tf.nn.top_k(pred_softmax, k=5, sorted=True)
final_value_top_5, result_top_5 = sess.run([pred_val, pred_top_5], feed_dict={x: test_images_norm, keep_prob: 1.})
```

Output of result_top_5:

```
print("Top Five Values : ", result_top_5)


Top Five Values :  
TopKV2(values=array([[ 0.99997199,  0.00002627,  0.00000093,  0.00000037,  0.00000026],
   [ 0.95321703,  0.03558423,  0.00697112,  0.00384381,  0.00017009],
   [ 0.99999988,  0.00000006,  0.00000003,  0.00000003,  0.00000001],
   [ 0.97826147,  0.00386234,  0.0029005 ,  0.00261023,  0.00211955],
   [ 0.95918149,  0.03276089,  0.00288947,  0.00224512,  0.00059758]], dtype=float32), indices=array([[16,  9, 17, 14,  0],
   [ 1,  2,  0,  4,  5],
   [38, 36,  3, 34, 15],
   [33,  4, 35, 39, 37],
   [11, 30, 12, 21, 28]], dtype=int32))
```

I want to print the output in the following way:

```
Probable class = "Car" ( I will check the mapping of highest prob with class label)

Class_ID   Prob
16      |0.99997199|
9       |0.00002627|
17      |0.00000093|
14      |0.00000037|
0       |0.00000026|
```

And so on..

I tried to use Tabulate and other utilities but I am not sure how to map the "TopKV2" elements "values" and "indices" with each other.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by adding the output from the Tabulate to pyplot. I added the text output to plt.text() and placed it next to the figures.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the evaluation results to pandas data frame like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

final_value_df = pd.DataFrame(final_value_top_5.T)
index_df = pd.DataFrame(result_top_5.T)
df = pd.concat(dict(Prob=final_value_df, Class_ID=index_df), axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
```

After this you can select and inspect any particular batch, e.g. `df.loc[:, 0]` will be exactly:

```py
   Class_ID          Prob
0        16  9.999720e-01
1         9  2.627000e-05
2        17  9.300000e-07
3        14  3.700000e-07
4         0  2.600000e-07
```